# Can these html tags and attribs make my site vulnerable?

Tags: javascript, html, security, exploit

I am developing a social website and want to allow user ONLY these html tags and attributes in their posts:

```
tags:  <img>,<b>, <strong>, <blockquote>, <a>
attribs:  'src', 'alt', 'width', 'height', 'href','class'
```

Any other tag will be filter out in the rendered html.
I am wondering this limited set also can open the door to some XXS or other exploits?

Comment: Yep: `<a href="javascript:alert(1);">`.

Comment: Ok, what if I also blacklist `javascript` ?

Comment: Also, I think `<img src="" alt="">` can have a PHP script as the source, but I’m not sure how dangerous this can be.

Comment: @Xufox It is not dangerous because CORS should not allow access to any of the site's cookies or DOM. The user could point the image source to an extremely large image, which could hang and even crash the client's browser tab. Some sites check the image size before displaying the image. If the image is too big, an explanation is shown: "Not automatically shown because <file size> is too large. View it directly `<a href="img_loc">here</a>`." Although this does not make the web server itself vulnerable, it is not a pleasant experience for your clients.

Comment: @usandfriends Checking the file size on submission doesn't work, because the size of the remote resource can be changed at any point. (You don't even need PHP to do that.)

Comment: @duskwuff I never said anything about checking on submission: "Some sites check the image size _before displaying the image_." If images are an important component to your website, I suggest implementing a CDN like most social media sites do. You would get the image URL, download the image to your CDN in the backend, and then replace the URL with your CDN URL. When the user switches the URL, delete the old CDN image and create a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would be vulnerable to XSS attacks if you allowed those tags and attributes, example:

```
<a href="javascript: code that sends users login cookie to hacker">click me!</a>
```

In the **request** (where a user submits potential XSS), use a *real* HTML parser (like JSoup) to **validate** your HTML against a whitelist.

In the **response** (where you display potential XSS) use a library to HTML **encode** the user input. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project

Read https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

usandfriends comment is not correct and this has nothing to do with CORS